# Recursively find directories but do not print subdirectories of matches

Tags: shell, find, regular-expression

Considering the following directory structure:

```
dir1
  [domain.com] foo dir1
    subdir1
  subdir2
    FooFile
dir2
  [domain.com] foo dir2
  subdir3
    [domain.com] foo dir3
      subdir4
      subdir5
    subdir6
  subdir7
[domain.com] foo dir4
  subdir8
```

I'd like to list all dirs with names that contain `[domain.com]`.
Desired output:

```
[domain.com] foo dir1
[domain.com] foo dir2
[domain.com] foo dir3
[domain.com] foo dir4
```

I'm having a hard time putting this together. The closest I have come:

```
find . -type d -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/(\[domain\.com\]).+" -exec basename {} \;
```

But this outputs subdirectories as well:

```
[domain.com] foo dir3
subdir5
subdir4
[domain.com] foo dir2
[domain.com] foo dir4
subdir8
[domain.com] foo dir1
subdir1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it looks like you have GNU find, this should be enough:

```
find . -type d -name '\[domain.com\]*' -printf '%f\n'
```

GNU `find`'s `-printf` action can print just the basename of the matched file with `%f`.

The problem with your regex is that it allows for anything after `[domain.com]` - even a `/`, and hence matches subdirectories. `".*/(\[domain\.com\])[^/]+"` might fix that issue.

Comment: Both solutions work for me. Thank you for the insights and clear explanation.